# What grammatical concept is used here? (“A that would have p.p. had B p.p.”)

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, inversion

The following is an excerpt from [**RFC 2616**: Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.13):

> ### §14.13 `Content-Length`
>
> The `Content-Length` entity-header field indicates the size of the entity-body, in decimal number of *OCTET*s, sent to the recipient or, in the case of the `HEAD` method, the size of **the entity-body that would have been sent had the request been a `GET`**.

. And this is my first time seeing this structure of a noun phrase:

> the entity-body that would have been sent **had** the request **been** a `GET`

. The meaning would be:

> the entity-body that would have been sent **if** the request **had been** a `GET`

, but how come? What has been omitted here? Is it an inversion? What grammatical concept is used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [**inversion in conditional clauses.**](https://www.englishgrammar.org/inversion-conditional-clauses/)

"If" gets omitted, the auxiliary verb moves to the beginning of the clause.

> Had I known that you were coming, I would have cleaned up.

If the  verb is a negative ("hadn't"), the "not" particle has to be separated from the auxiliary verb and moved to the side of the main verb.

> **Had** she **not helped** me I would have been in a lot of trouble.  *[this example is used in the link above]*

An inverted conditional clause sounds more formal and high-flown than a "normal" sequence.